.htaccess Hotlink prevention not working with [F], works with /403.html
I was trying to implement hotlink prevention on my site using .htaccess, but I encountered some issues.
I first tried this rule:
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?siteName\.com/.*$ [NC]

RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|jpeg|mp3|png|pdf|zip)$ - [F]

It didn't work.
Then I tried this
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?siteName\.com/.*$ [NC]

RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|jpeg|mp3|png|pdf|zip)$ - [F,L] 

it still didn't work.
But when I try this:
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?siteName\.com/.*$ [NC]

RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|jpeg|mp3|png|pdf|zip)$ - /403.html [F,L]

It worked. I don't know how by redirecting it can work. I am learning all by myself so if here someone can help me.

What exactly does "didn't work" mean? Did those resources still get delivered, with a 200 OK status code? Or did they perhaps actually get a 403 response - but not accompanied by the custom 403 error document you were expecting?
